# Select ResourceDictionary from XAML file in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть файл **Styles.xaml**, в нем есть несколько **ResourceDictionary** у которых есть **x:Key**.

Мне нужно в C# коде присвоить **Application.Current.Resources** ресурс с определенным **x:Key**.

Каким образом это можно сделать?

Comment: Покажите содержимое `Styles.xaml`

Comment: Хм, а почему бы не брать ресурс сразу из первоисточника, а не из `Styles.xaml`? Т.е. берем не в `Styles.xaml` по ключу `Style_Quad`, а берем сразу ресурс `[1] Style_Quad.xaml`

Comment: Т.е. под ключом `Style_Quad` будет скрыто несколько смерженных `ResourceDictionary`?

Comment: Ну а эти пачки по отдельным файлам разбить не вариант? Т.е. группируете несколько ResourceDictionary в один ResourceDictionary. Просто вот так по ключу как извлекать не совсем понятно, а отдельный ResourceDictionary - вроде не сложно

Comment: @Алексей: Ничего не понятно. Можете привести пример, для вашего кода какой вы даёте ключ, и какой результат хотите получить?

Comment: @Алексей: А что означает в вопросе «присвоить `Application.Current.Resources`»?

Comment: Уважаемый, уже бы давно расписали задачу подробнее. Скажем (Хочу покрасить табуретку, для этого хочу сходить в магазин и купить краску, но краска на верхней полке. Помогите, как ее достать? Я пытался стремянку поставить, да далековато...). Это если прям так, утрировать. Обычно все стили применяются в XAML разметке, вы же для чего то хотите это сделать в коде. Ведь вам уже дали ответ и это походу вам не подходит. Так можете подробней указать что, зачем и почему? Вам же самим лучше будет и мы (комьюнити), сможем быстрее вам помочь разобраться с этим.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ответ**:

App.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>             
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Styles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Style_Quad">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Style_Quad.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>

<ResourceDictionary x:Key="Style_Ellipse">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Style_Ellipse.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

C#

```
ResourceDictionary style = (ResourceDictionary)Application.Current.Resources["Style_Quad"];

Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(style);
```

Answer (score 1):

У меня работает так:

```
var rd = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Styles.xaml") };
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add((ResourceDictionary)rd["Style_Quad"]);
```

Добавил этот код в App.xaml.cs в метод `OnStartup`